# create new df3 with max values from df1 and corresponding values (same position) from df2

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new **df3** based on

**1)** finding the max value in each column of **df1** and

**2)** then appending a row with the corresponding values from **df2** (same position of **df1**)

**Input:**

```
data = [[2, 10], [5, 15], [7, 14]]
data1 = [[0.5, 0.25], [.55, .115], [.45, .414]]
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
    df1.max()
    df1.idxmax()
```

**Output: df1**

```
   0   1
0  2  10
1  5  15
2  7  14
```

**Output: df2**

```
      0      1
0  0.50  0.250
1  0.55  0.115
2  0.45  0.414
```

****Desired Output:** df3**

```
         0     1
0        7     15
1        0.45  0.115
```

Note: The columns in **df1** will be unique.

Comment: What if the maximum is not unique? Like two times 15 for column 1?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. They will be unique. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([df1.max().tolist(), [df2.at[row, col] for row, col in zip(df1.idxmax(), df1.columns)]])
```

Output:

```
      0       1
0  7.00  15.000
1  0.45   0.115
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to loop via creating a mask.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([df1.max(), df2.values.flatten('F')[(np.amax(df1.values, axis=0) == df1.values).flatten('F')]])
```

```
df3
###
      0       1
0  7.00  15.000
1  0.45   0.115
```